# Is the average temperature of a healthy human adult 98.6F/37C?

Tags: medical-science, biology, anatomy

## Everyone knows that...

> **Human body temperature - Wikipedia**
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_temperature
>   In humans, **the average internal temperature is 37.0 °C (98.6 °F)**, though it varies among individuals. However, no person always has exactly the same temperature at every moment of the day.

However, in recent [Freakonomics podcast “Bad Medicine, Part 1: The Story of 98.6.”](http://freakonomics.com/podcast/bad-medicine-part-1-story-98-6/), a guest researcher cast doubt on that number (which from what I understand is from research 100+ years old).

> In his study, Mackowiak found the actual “normal” temperature to be 98.2 degrees.

(i.e. 36.8 Celsius) What does actual scientific research say in 2016, as opposed to old medical textbooks?

Comment: [Related question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/do-japanese-people-have-a-lower-body-temperature-than-caucasians)

Answer (score 8):

The average rectal temperature is 36.85 °C

Relative to the average rectal temperature, other parts of the body are:

Mouth  -0.45 to -0.30

Esophagus -0.30 to -0.20

Stomach -0.20 to -0.10

Vagina -0.05 to +0.05

Brain -0.25 to +0.05

[Human Body Temperature: Its Measurement and Regulation](https://books.google.com/books?id=LDcLBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Human+Body+Temperature:+Its+Measurement+and+Regulation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW4YzHk9jQAhVB8IMKHb__A_IQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Human%20Body%20Temperature%3A%20Its%20Measurement%20and%20Regulation&f=false) Table 5.2

For more information see [Estimating changes in mean body temperature for humans during exercise using core and skin temperatures is inaccurate even with a correction factor](http://jap.physiology.org/content/103/2/443.full.pdf+html) which determines the mean esophagus, rectal and aural canal temperature as a function of minutes of exercise at two ambient temperatures (24 and 30 °C)

Mean rectal temperature at an ambient temperature of 24 °C at rest is:

**36.82 °C** with a standard deviation of 0.27 °C